# Is it possible to prevent the "Blob ... will be skipped for function ..." message from being logged repeatedly?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-trigger

I have an Azure function with a blob storage trigger pattern defined as

```
vanilla-v2-ratesheets-ci/{name}.xlsx
```

If I upload a text file as a blob to the *vanilla-v2-ratesheets-ci* container, then I get this trace message in Application Insights, **every 10 seconds**:

> Blob 'fsl/fi/BlobIgnore.txt' will be skipped for function
> 'Vanilla2PricelistFunction' because it does not match the pattern
> 'vanilla-v2-ratesheets-ci/{name}.xlsx'

It is completely redundant, but it continues ad infinitum. Anyone know how to stop this from happening?

Comment: where do you see the logs? in Application insights? it's better to provide a screenshot.

Comment: Please show more details.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @ChayanBansal - yes our solution was to make sure to remove the blob from the container once it's been processed!! This was the workaround we went with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we ended up with a workaround, rather than a solution:

1. Write code in the function to physically delete the blob from the container once it's been processed. This will obviously solve the immediate problem that the blobs get continually "ignored" 6 times per minute.

However, this is a non-native workaround - there should definitely be some way to trigger blob deletion automatically from the blob trigger interface, but this does not exist yet (hint hint, Microsoft?).